# How to access a structure

Tags: structure, best-practice

I'm trying to build a restaurant menu using a structure.
The structure looks like that:

```
> Menu-part 1
  > Menu-item 1
  > Menu-item 2
  > Menu-item 3

> Menu-part 2
  > Menu-item 4
  > Menu-item 5
  > Menu-item 6
```

How would I now make a page accessible with those entries ? Should I create a single-page and then add those categories ? Or is there a better way ?

**EDIT**
What I don't understand is: Do structures exist without any page behind it? Because what I want is a page that just takes every entry from my menu-structure and builds me the food-menu on `mysite.dev/lunch-menu` for example.

Comment: Hi @maxx, this question is very broad. Any potential answers will cover a lot of ground, much of which can be covered by simply [reading the docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries). Would you mind breaking this out into multiple, more specific questions? Or at least refining this question into a **specific** need more than a general one? And as always, it's helpful to provide code examples of anything you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

> Do structures exist without any page behind it?

No, you have to design a template for it. To make that template available under `mysite.dev/lunch-menu` you have multiple options.

The easiest way to do it is to simply save the template as `/lunch-menu/index.html`.

Another pretty common option is to use a Single section for your menu's Structure section index page. This is not very complicate to set up and because your "Lunch menu" now got it's own entry type, you can add custom fields to it. That's a good thing to have if you need other content on that lunch menu's index page besides the actual lists.

You could also create another structure (e.g. named "Pages") and make you Lunch menu structure's index page an entry of that other structure. Besides index pages, like the "Lunch menu" index or a "News" index for example, you could also add entries like "About" or "Contact" to that structure. One advantage of this approach is that you have all your pages (indexes and single content) in one structure and you can create your site navigation out of it.